# Take a deep breath

Tags: wordplay, knowledge, poetry

Here's a quick one that should be easy.

You've heard me before.
A Cinematic Icon
Perfect audio.

What am I?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I want to say...

> THX. I've definitely heard it before, I love the icon for it, and it's truly perfect to the ears.

Comment: I'm looking for the name of what you hear. Right brand, though.

Comment: hmm, are you referring to ROT13(gur "Qrrc Abgr")? :)

Comment: Yep ;) +5 for you!